# Trouble downgrading Ruby on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rvm, osx-mavericks

OS X 10.9 comes with ruby 2.0.0p195 but I need to install Ruby 1.8.7. I keep running into errors. I have Xcode5-DP install and I believe Command Line Tools is installed too.

In the terminal:

```
sudo rvm install 1.8.7
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/alextoul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #extracted to /Users/alextoul/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371 (already extracted)
Patch stdout-rouge-fix was already applied.
Patch no_sslv2 was already applied.
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #configuring...
Error running 'env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include -I/usr/local/opt/libxslt/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl098/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libxslt/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl098/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/alextoul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371 --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/alextoul/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p371/1371228839_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

1371228839_configure.log says:

```
./configure
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/alextoul/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Other (useful) info:

```
ruby -v
> ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
brew update
> Already up-to-date.
gcc --version
> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
> Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.1.58) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
> Thread model: posix
sudo rvm requirements
> Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
> Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: open an issue for rvm: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

10.9 is an early beta build of the OS. [*Edit: please note the July 2013 date of this answer*] If I were running 10.9 I would assume I'll have to reinstall the operating system from scratch at least 2 more times. (At least once during the beta cycle because, well, it's beta, and once when 10.9 comes out in general release, because, well, beta).

Given this I suggest four courses of action (pick 1 or many):

- Work with the RVM guys and dig into 10.9's probably-changed compiler environment and get Ruby 1.8.7 compiling. This is trickier because technically this stuff is under NDA.
- Instead, set up a VM and run Ruby 1.8.7 on the VM. Bonus points for using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) and Chef/Puppet, because you may even need to rebuild the VM. (Just keep the Vagrantfile and Puppet or Chef config files on Github/Dropbox/whatever so you can clone them and regenerate your VM from scratch.)
- OR simply reboot to 10.8 to get production work done. 10.8 is a production level OS, 10.9 should be treated with caution - it could eat your work. It really shouldn't be used for production purposes (aka: day to day writing Ruby code). If you're writing a 10.9 only app in Cocoa/Objective-C (or updating RubyMotion or something) that might be another thing (but I'd still keep good backups and treat it gently).
- Work towards updating your code base for Ruby 2.0, as Ruby 1.8.7 is no longer officially supported anyway.

**Edit (Oct 24, 2013):** If you're here because you just installed Mavericks (released Oct 22, 2013), want to get Ruby 1.8.7 working a few days after this release, and RVM isn't working for you (because you're impatient and can't wait), here's what you can do (which should work, although I'm not an rbenv user):

1. Use macports to install `port install ruby`. This is Ruby 1.8.7. This compilation worked for me on my Mavericks machine (although you will need to install Macports from source at this writing *and* install the command line developer tools, even if you have XCode 5 installed. Yes, really).
2. Now, install [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).
3. Symlink `/opt/local/bin/ruby1.8` in the `~/.rbenv/versions/` folder. Specifically `~/.rbenv/versions/ruby-1.8.7-p374`
4. Read the rbenv documentation, but it should work now! (At least from the documentation. Again, not an `rbenv` user, but do play one on TV)

I'm sure you can do this with homebrew too, but I know Ruby 1.8.7 installs correctly with the latest Macports, because that's what I use (and it just installed cleanly for me).

Comment: if it would be possible I would +1 every point of the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch.. I submitted an issue to the RVM guys. It actually doesn't work for Ruby 1.9.3 either and not sure I can upgrade to Ruby 2.0 that easily.. I will downgrade OSx for now and play around with it on a second computer..

Comment: Rather than rvm, try rbenv, which is preferred by the guys at GitHub and required by their [Boxen toolset](http://boxen.github.com), with which rvm is incompatible. I recently switched from rvm to rbenv, partly because of this, and it seems to work at least as well (albeit slightly differently). I haven't tried it yet on Mavericks, so I've no idea if it will work in this case, but it's worth a try. Have a look at these articles: http://www.overacker.me/blog/2013/07/10/getting-started-with-rbenv/ & http://edapx.com/2013/05/23/switching-from-rvm-to-rbenv/

Comment: BTW, read this article if you want to know why should consider using Boxen: http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/02/15/puppet-plus-github-equals-laptop-love/

Comment: Running in a separate isn't an option for everyone and not a solution to the question. Now that Maverick is no longer "beta" this non-answer is revealed for what it originally was, A non-answer. The problem persists and this answer does nothing to address it. Ofcourse we should work toward updating our code to 2.0 compatibility but this is something we preferably do at our own pace. This answer is something I'd expect to see on Expert Exchange where people provide useless responses for points. Is Stackoverflow becoming more like expert exchange?

Comment: Now that Mavericks is publicly released people can talk about it in public without fear of the NDA. The RVM team - for one - is pretty responsive about Mavericks issues now (just look at their Github issue tracker). You probably shouldn't downgrade the system Ruby, but use RVM/rbenv to install a separate Ruby for older projects. If rvm install fails, work with the RVM/rbenv developers to get a working Ruby. In fact there's an issue for REE support in 10.9 with a lot of activity open right now (for example).

Or wait a week, let the RVM team work through the issues, update RVM & try again.

Comment: @Beaon and, because I'm a nice guy, I've updated my answer that I hope you'll consider an actual answer answer.

Answer (score 10):

When you see this error message:

**configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables**:

First of all, make sure you have upgraded your commandline tools:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Now Apple wants you to agree to their license before you can use these tools:

```
$ gcc
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

$ sudo gcc
You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.
[...]
```

After you have accepted it, the commandline tools will work as expected.

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

Comment: yes I have Xcode 5.0.2. I solved this by just downloading the tools from the Apple dev center.

Answer (score 8):

If you've installed developer tools on OS X Mavericks Ruby 1.8 is already installed along with 2.0.
So all you need to do is switch the 'Current' symbolic link to point to the 1.8 directory.

```
#Install Xcode Developer tools
xcode-select --install

#Delete Current symbolic link to Ruby 2.0
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current

#Create new Current symbolic link to Ruby 1.8
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current

#Check Ruby version is 1.8.7
ruby -v
```

Comment: This one worked for me, after trying EVERYTHING for two days. Thanks!

Comment: By the way if you ever need to go back to 2.0, just delete the symbolic link and then create a new Current symbolic link replacing the /1.8 part with /2.0

Comment: this works particularly well if you did the free os upgrade such that both are installed and it fixes whatever it was you were already running on ruby1.8 instantly

Answer (score 3):

Try this (ensure the dev toolchain is reachable):

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your compiler

```
rvm install 1.8.7 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: this is asking for problems, `ruby-1.8.7` was not compatible with `clang` at all, first attempts to make it work were done in `ruby-1.9.3`, but only `ruby-1.9.3-p194` was working properly (minimal issues) and `ruby-2.0.0` was the first one that worked better with `clang` instead of `gcc-4.2` (the GNU GCC)