# Port install ruby stuck in Building gettext

Tags: ruby, macports, osx-mavericks

I've just installed *Mavericks OSX*, loosing my previous ruby versions which I used to work in several Redmine based projects. Not to say I'm currently not happy with apple.

Anyway, I'm following @RyanWilcox steps described here to install a ruby version prior `2.0`.-

[Trouble downgrading Ruby on OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113823/trouble-downgrading-ruby-on-os-x-mavericks)

which looks promising, but sadly I'm stuck installing `ruby` through `macports`. When I run

```
sudo port install ruby
```

everything seems ok, but then it get stuck in

```
--->  Building gettext
```

step. I'm not a `macports` user and have no idea what's happening here nor even where should I start looking. Anyone could point me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the xcode command line tools? Try `xcode-select --install` first.

I also suggest you to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead of MacPorts. Here are the steps to install rbenv via Homebrew: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv init
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile    
rbenv install 1.8.7-p374 # or any version listed in `rbenv install -l`
rbenv local 1.8.7-p374
```

Now 1.8.7 is the default Ruby version for your user.

Comment: Thanks @pstadler. Yes I have xcode installed, and run `xcode-select --install` just in case. I've installed `rbenv` as well, but I'm not able to install old ruby versions; the post I mentioned describes a 'hack' to install ruby 1.8.7 through macports, and then 'enabling' it through `rbenv`.

Comment: Still getting errors complaining about my gcc version. Anyway, I finally got it, it seems ruby 1.8.7 wasn't removed from the system; just changed `Current` symbolic link to point to 1.8.7 instead of 2.0, as @David proposes in the question's thread. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to switch to Xcode5 command-line tools, using `xcode-select -s <Xcode5 Developer folder path>`, because I had two versions of Xcode (4.6 and 5) on my machine and at the time of building ports I was using Xcode4 command-line tools.

Also, I enabled multi-core build in `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` by setting `buildmakejobs` field to:
`buildmakejobs          2`
This made the build process much faster, so that there are smaller chances that it would give you false impressions that it got stuck elsewhere.